# How to get Account.Name when Selecting Tasks in Salesforce SOQL

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am dealing with an SOQL query in Salesforce like

```
SELECT Id, Subject, Who.Name FROM Task
```

I need to know the Who.Account.Name in the same Query

How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was easy

```
  SELECT Id, Task.Account.Name, Subject, Who.Name FROM Task
```

Answer (score -3):

edit:  SELECT Contact.Account.Name FROM Contact

general info:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: I am interested in the who's account